# SQL function in color scheme doesn't change

Tags: sql, function, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, color-scheme

I made a custom color scheme in **PhpStorm 2021.2.2** and I noticed functions color in SQL doesn't change to what I configure,
In **"File" > "Settings" > "Editor" > "Color Scheme" > "SQL"**
It stays in white when I colored them in purple.

[image]

Even if I put a foreground color in **"General" > "Injected language fragment"** it colors everything but the functions, still white.

[image]

Not sure if is a bug in the IDE because is the same thing in built-in schemes, to do a little test I put the scheme in Darcula and changed the color and still stayed in yellow.

[image]

Anybody knows something about this detail?

Comment: 1) Place caret on such element 2) Open `Help | Find Action...` (or `Shift` x2 and witch to Actions tab) 3) Type `jump to` to locate "Jump to Colors and Fonts" entry. 4) Invoke that entry -- what will it show you? Add a screenshot to your question.

Comment: Right now this looks similar to these tickets: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-11461 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-14174 . They both look the same to me (1 is old and one is very recent).. and do not have any activity from dev side.